# How to wait for a function to be executed using promise to wait on its callback in Javascript/Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have two functions say `async foo()` and `bar()`

Lets say exe time of `foo()` => 5 seconds

exe time of          `bar()` => 10 seconds

Code looks something like

```
await foo();

async foo(){
//body 
bar()
}
```

**PROBLEM:**

Here `foo()` takes 5 seconds to execute (the body part) so it returns a successful promise without waiting for the execution of `bar()` to complete

**QUESTION:**

How do i make sure that `foo()` only returns a promise when `bar()` completes its execution maybe using promise to wait on the callback of `bar()` but i'm not sure how to exactly go about it

Note: Can't declare bar as async since it is imported from some other module

Comment: does `bar` returns a promise or accepts a callback?

Comment: if bar can be called independent of foo then you can use Promise.all https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: i'm not sure.. `bar` is imported from somewhere else actually `bar` is the function `ses.sendTemplatedEmail(params,err,data)`

Comment: I want the promise to be resolved when the `bar()` finishes it execution, But what typically happens is that it returns a promise without `bar()` having completed its execution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can promisify methods of `aws-sdk`'s services just by appending the method with `.promise`;

```
await foo();

foo(){
  return ses.sendTemplatedEmail(params).promise();
}
```

OR

```
    await foo();

    async foo(){
      try {
        let res = await ses.sendTemplatedEmail(params).promise();
        console.log(res)
     }catch(err) {
        console.log(err)
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code

```
await foo();

    foo() {
        return new Promise(async resolve => {
           const result =await bar()
              if (result) {
                resolve(true)   
              }

        })
      }
```

Comment: if `bar` is already a promise whats the point of wrapping it again inside a promise? Its an antipattern.

Comment: It's ok, take it as learning... You can update your answer, I will give you up vote. "Stay Hungry Stay Foolish".